# How to force a <div> to stay a fixed distance from the top of the screen when scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I want to place a `<div>` element with some longer text in it on a webpage with a fixed top spacing of 30px. The problem is that whenever I'm scrolling down, the `<div>` doesn't stay in place and so the spacing disappears.
I'm looking for a CSS-only solution.

This document illustrates my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style = "width: 10px; top: 50px; margin-top: 50px; padding-top: 50px;
      position: absolute;">
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
      text to enable scrolling.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `position: fixed`

Comment: or `position: sticky;` https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/ depending on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: or do you want to scroll INSIDE the div?

Comment: @bruno: No, I'd like to avoid that ideally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you're saying that you want to keep 30 pixels spacing on the top of the div, but still want to be able to scroll down? In that case, i think you have to make the div itself scrollable. But since that's not what you want, how about overlaying another `div` with `position:fixed` and the same background color?

```html
  <body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
      text to enable scrolling.<br>
    </div>
  </body>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2000;
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this css rule for your fixed `<div>`.

```
.yourfixeddiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem with this is that longer text will not visible anymore. I need to maintain the ability to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need margin-top if you are absolutely positioning.

position: sticky with top: 50px; should achieve what you want

```css
div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed;` is the way to keep an element in place. Important is to use a `width`. More information here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/